Unable to interact with google maps with selenium to get route details
I am trying to interact with google maps to get route related data. Here is what I have written so far.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.ID, 'hArJGc').click()
time.sleep(5)
search_boxes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tactile-searchbox-input')
search_boxes[0].clear()
search_boxes[0].send_keys('Hyderabad')
search_boxes[1].clear()
search_boxes[1].send_keys('Guntur')
search_boxes[1].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-dropdown').click()

I am trying to access the drop down button to set departure time by passing its class name. but it is saying such element does not exists as shown below
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-dropdown"}
  (Session info: chrome=124.0.6367.91); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AEF11502+60802]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEE8AC02]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AED47CE4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AED96D4D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AED96E1C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEDDCE37]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEDBABBF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEDDA224]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEDBA923]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AED88FEC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AED89C21]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AF21411D+3217821]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AF2560B7+3488055]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AF24F03F+3459263]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AEFCB846+823494]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEE95F9F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEE90EC4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEE91052]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7AEE818A4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFAFC8E257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFAFE42AA48+40]

But when I inspect the webpage that class name exists. How come I am not able to access it like other elements and how to resolve this?
thanks in advance!


Issues:

As soon as the URL is launched Accept/Reject cookies pop-up comes up. You need to get rid of it

Below code is incorrect. There are 2 classes goog-inline-block and goog-menu-button-dropdown. If there are multiple classes CLASS_NAME locator will not work.
By.CLASS_NAME, 'goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-dropdown' 


Use selenium's waits, instead of time.sleep()


Here is the refactored and working code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# below line will click on Accept all cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//span[text()='Accept all'])[1]"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "hArJGc"))).click()

search_boxes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'tactile-searchbox-input')))
search_boxes[0].clear()
search_boxes[0].send_keys('Hyderabad')
search_boxes[1].clear()
search_boxes[1].send_keys('Guntur')
search_boxes[1].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-dropdown']"))).click()
time.sleep(20)

